# Hypothesis testing, find $n$ to limit type II errors

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample-size

I'm trying to solve the following (basic) problem, but I don't seem to get the last part 3).

> The average lifespan of a certain mechanical part is set to be **at least** 2 years by experts. The distribution is known to be normal with a deviation of 4 months. 9 parts are chosen at random and the average lifespan of these parts appears to be 2,2 years.
>
> 1. Determine at 1% significance level if the experts are right.
> 2. Calculate for this test the probability of a type II error if the average lifespan would be 2,25 year.
> 3. How much parts should have been examined in the test above to have an probability of type II error of at most 1%.

### I have tried:

1) Using $H_0: \mu = 2$, $H_1: \mu > 2$

$$T = \frac{\overline X_n - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} = 1,8 < z_{\alpha} = 2,325$$

In conclusion: we do not reject $H_0$

2) I'm firstly looking for $\overline X_n$ for which I would reject $H_0$.

$$\text{rejecting }H_0 \Leftrightarrow \overline X_n \geqslant 2,325\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} = 2,258$$

Then I'm calculating 
$$\begin{align}
P(\overline X_n < 2,258 \mid \mu = 2,25) & = P\left(Z < \frac{2,258-2,25}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\right)\\
& = P(Z < 0,072)\\
& = 0,53
\end{align}$$

3) But now I get stuck.

It seems like:
$$P\left(Z < \frac{2,258-2,25}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\right) \leqslant 0,01$$

or

$$P\left(Z >\frac{2,258-2,25}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\right) > 99,99$$

but I don't see how I could calculate that? It seems like $\frac{2,258-2,25}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} < -2,325$ but that doesn't make any sense...

Could anyone give me some pointers? What am I doing wrong? (The book's answer is 39)